# android camera2 handle zoom

Tags: android, zooming, capture, android-camera2

I'm new in Android Camera2 API.
I just move my all project to the new Camera2 API. I have used the [Camera2Basic example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2basic/Camera2BasicFragment.java) as a starting point.

I'm now trying handle zoom by adding this:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    try {
        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(mCameraId);
        float maxZoom = (characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_AVAILABLE_MAX_DIGITAL_ZOOM))*10;

        Rect m = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_INFO_ACTIVE_ARRAY_SIZE);
        int action = event.getAction();
        float current_finger_spacing;

        if (event.getPointerCount() > 1) {
            // Multi touch logic
            current_finger_spacing = getFingerSpacing(event);

            if(finger_spacing != 0){
                if(current_finger_spacing > finger_spacing && maxZoom > zoom_level){
                    zoom_level++;

                }
                else if (current_finger_spacing < finger_spacing && zoom_level > 1){
                    zoom_level--;

                }
                int minW = (int) (m.width() / maxZoom);
                int minH = (int) (m.height() / maxZoom);
                int difW = m.width() - minW;
                int difH = m.height() - minH;
                int cropW = difW /100 *(int)zoom_level;
                int cropH = difH /100 *(int)zoom_level;
                cropW -= cropW & 3;
                cropH -= cropH & 3;
                Rect zoom = new Rect(cropW, cropH, m.width() - cropW, m.height() - cropH);
                mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.SCALER_CROP_REGION, zoom);
            }
            finger_spacing = current_finger_spacing;
        }
        else{
            if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                //single touch logic
            }
        }

        try {
            mCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewRequestBuilder.build(), mCaptureCallback,
                    null);
        }
        catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (NullPointerException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    catch (CameraAccessException e)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("can not access camera.", e);
    }

    return true;
}
```

And this:

```
private float getFingerSpacing(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
    return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
}
```

But after I captured, the picture result is without the zoom.
How can I make it happen?
Thanks all.

**Update**
Need to add `captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.SCALER_CROP_REGION, zoom);` to `captureStillPicture()` method.

Comment: Yes, Added my solution below

Comment: what is captureStillPicture() method???

Comment: after which line in captureStillPicture(). I tried to add everywhere but stills the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Need to add `captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.SCALER_CROP_REGION, zoom);` 
to the `captureStillPicture()` method.

Comment: mPreviewRequestBuilder values returns null why its occur 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68755703/how-to-do-when-taking-before-picture-zoomin-and-zoomout-camerrenderer-android-xa

please see this link

Answer (score 4):

You've only set the `SCALER_CROP_REGION` on the `CaptureRequestBuilder` for the recurring preview camera output. You just need to add the same crop region property to the `CaptureRequestBuilder` that uses the `ImageSaver`'s JPEG `Surface` as the output, and you should be all set.

Comment: Can you be more spesific please? In which method it shuld be display?

Comment: @EliElezra you must call set.(CaptureRequest.SCALER_CROP_REGION) in the builder that you sent to the photo when you capture it. The builder contains all the information about the preview that you are watching and the photo that its going to be save. You can modify preview and photo settings parametters in your builder. 

You can see more information in: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics.html

PD: I let you a post below of how i did it, take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Global:

```
companion object {
    private const val ZOOM_GESTURE_SENSITIVITY = .0005f
    private const val MAX_ZOOM_FACTOR = 3f
}

private var fingerDistance: Float? = null
private var zoom = 1f
```

Listener:

```
textureView.setOnTouchListener({ _, event ->
    if (event.action != MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE || event.pointerCount <= 1) {
        fingerDistance = null
        return@setOnTouchListener true
    }
    val newFingerDistance = with(event) {
        val x = getX(0) - getX(1)
        val y = getY(0) - getY(1)
        sqrt(x * x + y * y) * resources.displayMetrics.density
    }
    if (fingerDistance != null) {
        val manager = getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE) as CameraManager
        val characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId)
        val maxZoom = min(MAX_ZOOM_FACTOR, characteristics.get(
                CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_AVAILABLE_MAX_DIGITAL_ZOOM))
        val zoomChange = (newFingerDistance - fingerDistance!!) * ZOOM_GESTURE_SENSITIVITY
        zoom = min(maxZoom, max(1f, zoom + zoomChange))
        val sensorSize = characteristics.get(
                CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_INFO_ACTIVE_ARRAY_SIZE)!!
        val cropW = (sensorSize.width() * (1 - 1 / zoom) / 2).toInt()
        val cropH = (sensorSize.width() * (1 - 1 / zoom) / 2).toInt()
        val zoomRect = Rect(cropW, cropH,
                sensorSize.width() - cropW,
                sensorSize.height() - cropH)
        previewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.SCALER_CROP_REGION, zoomRect)
    }
    fingerDistance = newFingerDistance
    try {
        captureSession
                ?.setRepeatingRequest(previewRequestBuilder.build(), captureCallback, null)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    true
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set `SCALER.CROP.REGION` to the `captureBuilder` . You can do it in this way:

```
yourCapturebuilder.(CaptureRequest.SCALER_CROP_REGION, newZoom);
```

In other way, if you want to keep the Zoom in a preference. I suggest you do something like this: Save the Rect in a preference as a String and later on recover it to use it, or call it every time you open the camera:

```
Preferences.edit().putString(CameraSettings.KEY_ZOOM,newZoom.toString());
```

Later call this method to set the zoom dynamically:

```
public boolean setZoomValue(CaptureRequest.Builder builder) {
        Log.i(TAG,"zoom preference value " + mPreferences.getString(CameraSettings.KEY_ZOOM,null));
        String rawZoomValue =  mPreferences.getString(CameraSettings.KEY_ZOOM, null);
        if (rawZoomValue == null)
            return false;
        rawZoomValue = rawZoomValue.replaceAll("[Rect() ]", "");
        String[] rectZoomList = rawZoomValue.split(",|\\-|\\)|\\(");
        Rect zoomValue = new Rect( Integer.parseInt(rectZoomList[0]), Integer.parseInt(rectZoomList[1]), Integer.parseInt(rectZoomList[2]),Integer.parseInt(rectZoomList[3]));
        builder.set(CaptureRequest.SCALER_CROP_REGION, zoomValue);
        Log.i(TAG, "Zoom applied: " + zoomValue);
        return true;

    }
```