# pointerIndex out of range exception came whenever i touch the event Android multitouch

Tags: events, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, touch

Whenever i touch the event call and pointer index exception came and crash the app in android xamarin forms

```
/** Determine the space between the first two fingers */
    private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);

        return (float)Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }
```

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

```
ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
dumpEvent(event);

// Handle touch events here...
switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    savedMatrix.set(matrix);
    start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
    Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG");
    mode = DRAG;
    break;
case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
    oldDist = spacing(event);
    Log.d(TAG, "oldDist=" + oldDist);
    if (oldDist > 10f) {
        savedMatrix.set(matrix);
        midPoint(mid, event);
        mode = ZOOM;
        Log.d(TAG, "mode=ZOOM");
    }
```

}

Comment: have you checked `PointerCount` to determine how many elements exist?

Comment: @Jason No sir, i just calling the function OnTouchevent getting space between two fingers

Comment: my point is, you are assuming there are two sets of coordinates when apparently there are not.   Checking `PointerCount` would allow you to test this before you execute your code.

Comment: @Jason like if(event.getPointerCount() == 2) or otherway

Comment: Yes, test it first

Comment: @Jason i have one doubt there is no implementation in zoomin and zoomout in xamarin android so many stackoverflow check linking check android code there is not working for me, if any sample it there

Comment: @Jason please see this link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68755703/how-to-do-when-taking-before-picture-zoomin-and-zoomout-camerrenderer-android-xa/68769385#68769385